# QGIS 2.12 symbology does not work correctly

Tags: qgis, symbology, osx, vector-layer, qgis-2.12

I use QGIS for a long times on mac and windows and I have a problem with the 2.12 version on my OSX 10.8.5 when I want to edit style of my vector layer.

When I click on properties of a vector layer and I want to edit the style, QGIS tells me that `This layer doesn't have any editable properties`. I attach a file to be as clear as possible. Is anyone having the same problem ? Do you find a solution?

I had the same problem with the 2.10 version.

[image: Edit layer properties as usually do]

Comment: You might contact the QGIS Mac developers on the issue. There was a similar problem with rasters http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162 which should have been solved with QGIS 2.12. Your problem with vector data seems to remain.